# Angular js Onchange Event Not fired while using custom directive in input type text

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js. im trying to restrict only number with custom directive in input element  its working fine. while im triggering on change event its not fired

```
<input type="text" name="app_NoOfDaysOnRoad"
       data-ng-model="Appln.app_NoOfDaysOnRoad"
       ng-change="fnExpensesAndViabilityCal()"
       class="form-control"
       numbers-only placeholder="No of Days on Road" />
```

Comment: Can you share plnkr to reproduce the issue?

Comment: above html code having custom directive numbers only and ng-change event. once i removed my directive its working fine

Comment: Yeah we can check the directive if you share else you can go for $watch..

Comment: The [ng-change directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)  is only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the model using the [$setViewValue API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setViewValue).

Comment: If you want to restrict to numbers only,  use [<input type="number"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D).

Comment: oh thanks. ill try